# In C, find global const variable value when compiling

Tags: c, variables, toolchain

```
const int hello= 0x1111;
int main(){
}
```

I build a really simple code, and compile it with

```
gcc t.c -g -o t.out
```

Can I use objdump or nm or any tools to make sure the const variable value?
I always find address of variable "hello", but cannot find value

Anyone can help me, thanks a lot

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: show the output

Answer (score 1):

The example code

```
const int hello = 0xdeadbeef;
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
gcc-4.9   -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -std=c11 fortests.c -o fortests
```

dump the content with

```
objdump -xDSs fortests | less
```

(dumped a bit too much, but costs nothing, so ... meh ...) and search for `hello`

```
0000000000400594 g     O .rodata        0000000000000004              hello
```

That means it is in the section `.rodata`. We explicitly asked `objdump` to list the contents of all sections, so here we have it, the value `0xdeadbeef`.

```
Contents of section .rodata:
  400590 01000200 efbeadde                    ........ 
                  ^^^^^^^^
             here ||||||||
```

And it should be clear by now, why you had trouble to find it.